# Cross join filtering (exclude certain pairs)

Tags: matrix, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table that has currency pairs and it's loaded via a cross join and looks like this:

[Pairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxYQb.png)

The values in green are the ones I need to keep and the ones in red the ones I don't, since for example, I already have EUR-USD, I don't need USD-EUR.

Is there a way to filter a cross join to avoid doing it? If don't, what is the best way to get rid of the "red lines"? I can't use loop/cursors. It has to be a delete statement or a filter in the where of the cross join clause.

The cross join code:

```
select 
    pair_1, pair_2
from 
    (select distinct name as pair_1 from TABLE_NAME),
    (select distinct name as pair_2 from TABLE_NAME)
where
    pair_1 <> pair_2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care which sets of the duplicate pairs you keep?  If not, you could simply do `where pair_1 < pair_2` (or `pair_1 > pair_2`).  You really should use the SQL 99 join syntax with an explicit `cross join` in this sort of query though rather than using the old implicit join syntax.  That makes it much, much more likely that a future developer will understand that you intended to create a Cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Justin. Yes, I'll change to SQL99 convention, although I'm the only one to maintaining this... :)

Didn't know one could use lexographical ordering on SQL. 
Thanks a lot.